# Can we avoid space leaks in the Writer monad by making mappend non-strict on the second parameter

Tags: haskell, space-leak, writer-monad

I recently read about the space leak issue of the `Writer`/`WriterT` monad. If I correctly understood this problem, it is because the bind operator, i.e. `(>>=)` is not tail-recursive:

```hs
m >>= f = WriterT $ do
    (a, w1) <- runWriterT m
    (b, w2) <- runWriterT (f a)
    return (b, w1 `mappend` w2)
```

With the definition of `WriterT` and `Writer`:

```hs
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (a, w) }
type Writer w = WriterT w Identity
```

I am curious about whether introducing laziness on the second parameter of `mappend` would solve this space-leak problem.

By introducing laziness, I mean something like the `(++)` operator:

```hs
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

The result is produced without actually touching the second parameter.

Now, if we use a monad `m` with lazy monadic bind (e.g. `m ~ Identity`, which gives us the plain old `Writer` monad), and use `mappend` mentioned above, then the `f a` part (`w2`) can remain a thunk while evaluating `mappend w1 w2`, thus the result can be partially consumed (`w1`) without actually forcing the rest expression (`w2`).

Am I correct on this? Are space leaks avoided in such `Writer` monads?

Comment: `Writer` is just `WriterT` with `m ~ Identity`, and the space leak issue with `Writer` is frequently discussed using the list monoid so `++` **is** the `mappened` operation, which as you note is lazy in the second parameter.

Comment: @Ben, I understand that `Writer w ~ WriterT w m`, as well as `mappend = (++)` in the list monoid. Given that the general `WriterT` has space leak problems, what I wonder was whether this also apply to the simple `Writer` monad with lazy `mappend`. I am asking **whether space leaks also happen** in such situations.

Comment: It would leak.  See https://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2016/7/writer-monads-and-space-leaks

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I have read that before. Actually, I learned about space leaks on `Writer` monads just from that blog. But it did not clarify the space leak issue when `mappend` does not force the evaluation of its second parameter.

Comment: I found Getty's write up really fitting "notice that in order to start evaluating the call to mappend in step C, we need to have the output from both steps A and B. …except step B represents evaluating the entire rest of the computation, including an arbitrarily large number of other calls to >>=".  I.E. the leak happens before mappend is ever called.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Oh, I got it. I finally noticed the `b` in the bind operator. That result is from the second action, so the second action should still performed before `mappend`.

Comment: @Krantz Apologies for being unclear. I was trying to say that your 2 suggestions are usually present in examples given when discussing the problem, which wouldn't be the case if your 2 suggestions avoided the problem.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. I think I know the actual issue now. The leak happens because of the non-tail-recursive nature of the bind operator, not because of strictness.